# staging all files except specific files using glob patterns in git

Tags: git, shell, github, glob

I am trying to stage some new created files and some others edited files to my staging area in git using **git add** command. What I exactly want is to **stage everything except *.java** files (in my **current directory** and in **every sub directory** in my project). I tried to get that work with NO success.

pwd: /d/myProject

Nothing of these worked:

```
git add !(*.java)
git add \!\(\*.java\)
git add \!\(*.java\)
git add !\(\*.java\)
```

**Could somebody help me to get that work please?** And is it somehow possible to use regular expressions instead of globs here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `find`:

```
find . -type f ! -iname '*.java' -exec git add {} +
```

You can also skip paths matching a pattern by using `! -ipath <pattern>`, e.g:

```
find . -type f ! -iname '*.java' ! -ipath './a/b/*c*' -exec git add {} +
```

Comment: but here I will get a list of all files, not only not staged or the updated files, doesn't that hurt my repository?

Comment: @Mohammed: `add`ing a tracked file which is unchanged is a nop. To exclude some others, the `! -path <pattern>` argument to `find` might be helpful.

Comment: sorry but I am not very familier with those globs, could you explain those for me? './a/b/*c*' and the empty braces with plus {} +

Comment: `-exec git add {} +` executes `git add` for sets of found filenames (similar to `xargs`). `*` in the pattern matches any string. For example, these paths would match: `./a/b/c` or `./a/b/c/d/source`'

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the glob settings of your shell. What you can do for have a more system-independent behavior is to use find:

```
find . -not -iname '*.java' -exec git add '{}' \+
```

Comment: but here I will get a list of all files, not only not staged or the updated files, doesn't that hurt my repository?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin: this is not a problem, using `git add` with a file that is already up to date or in the `.gitignore` has no effect.

Comment: Thank you, for your help